# Jenkins - how to override credentials plugin usage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins Freestyle jobs, many Jenkins plugins uses a credential plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin
But we don't want Jenkins to store any credentials and would like the job will be executed using a Jenkins service user - the user that runs Jenkins service on the 
agent.
Is there any option to override this plugin usage?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs you just have to disable security:

[image]

You can find this tab in Jenkins-> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security